# Javascript date constructor on Cordova WP8

Tags: javascript, cordova, date, windows-phone-8

I have a date string in the format `28-Dec-2016 04:25 AM` and need to convert it to a `Date` object. For this, I first split the string to get the date and time

```
cDateStringParts = cdate.split(' ');
```

Then I get the date and time components

```
cDateParts = cDateStringParts[0].split('-');
cTimeParts = cDateStringParts[1].split(':');
```

Then I initialize the `Date` object like

```
if(cDateStringParts[2]=='AM'){
    cDateObject = new Date(cDateParts[2], convertToNumericMonth(cDateParts[1]), cDateParts[0], cTimeParts[0], cTimeParts[1], 0, 0);
} else {
    cDateObject = new Date(cDateParts[2], convertToNumericMonth(cDateParts[1]), cDateParts[0], complaintTimeParts[0] + 12, cTimeParts[1], 0, 0);
}
```

where `convertToNumericMonth()` is a function which converts Jan-Dec to 0-11.But I do not get the correct values when I check `cDateObject.getDate()/getMonth()/getYear()`. The result is 2017/12/29.

What am I doing wrong? If I try to do `alert(cdate,' ',cDateObject.getFullYear()` I get this:

[image]

Comment: whats the result you get?

Comment: for 28-Dec-2016 I get 2017/12/29

Comment: i am not sure but it might be a time zone issue

Comment: `new Date( Date.UTC())` this migt be helpful....

Comment: why you are splitting into date use directly var date = new Date('28-Dec-2016 04:25 AM') it converts in date object

Comment: No, directly initializing using the string gives NaN values

Comment: if you are checking in browser console then its give me result

Comment: Wed Dec 28 2016 04:25:00 GMT+0530 (IST) and if you access the date.getFullYear() then it returns 2016

Comment: In the WP8 emulator it gives `NaN/12/29`, checking using alert()

Comment: does the answer make any sense?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cVE2E/

Comment: Please give me value ,which passed  to date object from your exact code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse DateTime string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-datetime-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is how 12hr time is converted to 24hr time. The date parts are strings, so for "03:45 PM" the following:

```
complaintTimeParts[0] + 12
```

will return "0312". Also, "12:00 AM" should have the hours set to 0, but your code will set the hours to 12.

The hours can be converted to 24hr time by converting to a number first, converting 12am to 0 and then adding 12 if it's PM. Also simpler if done separately from the rest of the calculation:

```
var hr = cTimeParts[0] % 12 + (cDateStringParts[2]=='AM'? 0 : 12);
```

Here the mod operator `%` will convert `cTimeParts[0]` to a number. Now the function can be:

```js
function dateParse(cdate) {
  var cDateStringParts = cdate.split(' ');
  var cDateParts = cDateStringParts[0].split('-');
  var cTimeParts = cDateStringParts[1].split(':');
  var hr = cTimeParts[0] % 12 + (cDateStringParts[2]=='AM'? 0 : 12);
  return new Date(cDateParts[2], convertToNumericMonth(cDateParts[1]),
                  cDateParts[0], hr, cTimeParts[1]);
}

function convertToNumericMonth(month) {
  return {Jan:0,Feb:1,Mar:2,Apr:3,May:4,Jun:5,Jul:6,
          Aug:7,Sep:8,Oct:9,Nov:10,Dec:11}[month];
}

console.log(dateParse('28-Dec-2016 04:25 AM').toString());
console.log(dateParse('28-Dec-2016 04:25 PM').toString());
```

Lastly, missing parts are set to 0 (or 1 for the date) so they don't need to be included.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488313/javascripts-getdate-returns-wrong-date) might be a solution for your issue.

you cannot actually rely on the date parsing because, it is dependent on multiple factors like time zones, daylight saving etc.

you could also check your device's time zone and time settings because, the browser uses system data for parsing date.

i have checked the same logic on my browser and it worked fine for me.

here is the example.

[image: AM example]

[image: PM example]

if it is working this way, the issue would be that the values calculated by cDateParts is generating different values(very less possibility).

hope this would help you.

Comment: It works this way, but in case my time is in PM, I was adding 12 to hours being passed, which creates the problem.

Comment: @Sumit i am not sure why its not working proper.. its working like a charm on my pc