# Javascript .getDate() : getting 31 instead of 1

Tags: javascript

When I create the following date variable:

```
    var d = new Date('2018-01-01')
```

and run

```
    d.getDate()
```

I get 31. when I run

```
d.getMonth()
```

I get 11.

Why do I get 31 and 11 rather than 1 and 1?

Comment: Please change your title to ask a question or describe your problem.

Comment: Because the months are zero count `0-11`.

Comment: So then why don't I get 0 for 1? Why does it go to 11?

Comment: Also note the use of [date strings are discouraged for the Date constructor due to differences in browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488313/javascripts-getdate-returns-wrong-date

Comment: In that post, the output seems to be one number off. I'm not sure why I'm getting 31, 11 rather than 1, 0.

Comment: The short answer is that ISO 8601 format dates are treated as UTC. If your timezone is west of Greenwich, the local date becomes 2017-12-31 (and months are zero indexed hence *getMonth* returns 11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you live in the western hemisphere, this is a timezone issue, I believe.

Javascript timers are based on [Unix ticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)(basically seconds since January 1, 1970).
Since date-only format strings using ISO 8601 are treated as UTC, Javascript mitigates it by adding your local timezone, thus adjusting your time.

Example: 2018-01-01 00:00:00 - your timezone = 2017-12-31 {your timezone offset}.

You can recreate this by moving your timezone to negative UTC, try creating a date using the `new Date('string')` method, then getting the date.

You can fix this by using the `new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);` method instead.

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) a better understanding to it.

Comment: I've found that date.getUTCDate() will do what is expected here.


`date.getDate('2023-02-01') = 31` BUT `date.getUTCDate('2023-02-01') = 01`

Answer (score 0):

The months are 0 indexed, meaning they start from 0 and go up to 11.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't I get 0 and 0?

Comment: @Chip you should be getting 1 for the getDate() and 0 for the getMonth()
see: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp