# unable to get the date format

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'm trying to change the date format in javascript where in a variable i m getting the date value like this "11/09/2019" and want to change in a format like this "11-09-2019".but somehow i'm getting this format "sat nov 09 2019" whereas it should be "tue sep 11 2019".

can anyone help me. any help would be appreciated.

```
var alt_date1 = "11/09/2019";

var date = new Date(alt_date1);

alert(date);
```

> output: Sat Nov 09 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want a different format i.e., "-" instead of "/" and you're also getting the wrong date? 2 days ahead? Depending on your environment (browser, node, etc) the Date API can behave differently. I think this link might help you: [JavaScript's getDate returns wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488313/javascripts-getdate-returns-wrong-date) (Not sure though, some answers pertain to the time zones it uses)

As for formatting look here:
https://codehandbook.org/javascript-date-format/

Example from that site:

```
let current_datetime = new Date()
let formatted_date = current_datetime.getDate() + "-" + (current_datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + current_datetime.getFullYear()
console.log(formatted_date)

// output
"19-10-2018"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit tricky to understand the question fully, but if you don't need a Date object, and you want to just format the string as **11-09-2019** it can be achieved with the simple `replace` function like this:

`alt_date1.replace(/\//g, '-')`