# JavaScript Date.getDay() with hardcoded date returning wrong day?

Tags: javascript, date

A JSFiddle is worth 1000 words:
https://jsfiddle.net/cnuss/6731pakm/1/

What I'm seeing is that `date.getDay()` is returning the wrong value.

```
function getDay(date: Date) {
  return "The current day is: " + date.getDay();
}


document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = getDay(new Date('2020-04-06'));
```

The return value is `The current day is: 0`

`2020-04-06` is most certainly a Monday. So it should return 1?

What's going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript's getDate returns wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488313/javascripts-getdate-returns-wrong-date)

Comment: What timezone are you living in? It does return 1 for me.

Comment: I'm in America/Los_Angeles

Comment: '2020-04-06' is parsed as UTC, *getDay* returns the local day so if you're west of Greenwich, it will be 5 April so return 0 for Sunday.