# getFullYear on ISO date

Tags: javascript, date

I need to getFullYear on a JavaScript Date, however newing up a Date() creates it at UTC, and in the cases of January 1, it becomes LAST YEAR. (at my timezone, EST)

so:

```
startDateYear = new Date('2019-01-01').getFullYear()
```

returns 2018

I know .getISODate() does get the true date in my timezone, but I need to come up with a way to chain .getISODate() with .getFullYear() to get the true year.

Comment: check it out this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488313/javascripts-getdate-returns-wrong-date

Comment: Thanks, there were some good ideas in multiple answers.

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD is parsed as UTC, so use [*getUTCFullYear*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCFullYear) or keep it simple: `'2019-01-01'.substring(0,4)` or `'2019-01-01'.split('-')[0]`. :-)